# Finding common points of $\cos x$ and $(1/2)^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This might be easy math for you guys but I'm just not getting it.

Question says,graph:

$y= \cos x$

$y=(\frac{1}{2})^x$

On the same axis. Easy enough.

Next part says, state $4$ points where the two intersect.

I think they mean algebraically, because other way it would be too easy.

So I did $\cos x=(\frac{1}{2})^x$ and blanked out.

I tried a learning resource for Grade $12$ math to no avail.

Am I misunderstanding the question? If not, how do I solve this?

Hints are just as good as answers, thanks for your help!

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think it is possible to algebraically find any point other than $(0,1)$.

Comment: I think you may be right because this level of question would get insta answers otherwise. So I guess I should just do it graphically and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the way to go, unless someone comes up with a brilliant method to crack this.

Comment: You are right, there is no other algebraic solution other than $x=0$. But this makes me wonder if he is allowed to use numerical methods, Mathematica, a provided program .... Any hints that you can offer LoadingCode as to what tools you are allowed to use knowing full well that there are no exact solutions to this that can be found algebraically other than $x=0$? For example, what is the course title? I can certainly tell you numerically and graphically what happens in a heartbeat. I could even put out 4 or more approximate solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to gamble on approximate solutions being the best solutions. The equation $\cos(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$ clearly has integer solution $x=0$. There will be no other rational solutions, and that is a discussion probably deserving its own page. There is certainly no algebraic solution. However, we can find infinitely many approximate solutions, each becoming better by the following logic:

As $x$ approaches infinity (becomes larger), the function $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$ monotonically converges to zero. Formally,
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x =0.$$

The $\cos(x)$ function however has zeroes wherever $x=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$, where $n$ is an integer ($n\in\mathbb{Z}$).

What this specifically means in regards to finding approximate solutions to the equation $\cos(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x$, is that as $n$ becomes larger, the solution $x=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}, \, n \in \mathbb{N}$ becomes more exact.

It should be said that the $x$ intersections will never be rational for $x>0$.

Just for fun you might declare that, other than $x=0$, you can declare a solution that is more precise than any other in the class. For example, other than $x=0$, I doubt that anyone will declare a more exact solution than $x=\dfrac{\left(2 \cdot 10^{100}+1\right) \pi}{2}$. I usually save googols for when I really need them though in circumstances like these.

Answer (score 1):

As also noted in the comments, I believe it's safe to say that you're out of luck obtaining many "exact" solutions, since you are dealing with the transcendental equation $ \ \cos x \ - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^x = 0 \ $ .  I rather suspect that you *are* being asked to find solutions graphically...

Since $ \ -1 \le \cos x \le +1 \ , $ it's pretty straightforward to show that any solutions *must* be non-negative, and of course we can spot $ \ x = 0 \ $ as a solution "by inspection".  Also, because $ \ 0 \ < \ \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^x \ <  1 \ $ for $ \ x > 0 \ , $ we expect there to be two solutions in the intervals $ \ ( -\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi \ , \ \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi )  \ $ for positive integers $ \ k \ $ , with the solutions rapidly growing closer and closer to the $ \ x-$intercepts at $ \ x = \frac{2n+1}{2} \pi \ $ .

[This is pretty much redundant to **J.W. Perry**'s answer, since I took too long to finish typing it out...]

**EDIT [12/27/13] --**

I thought I'd revisit this problem once I found some time, since I couldn't quite leave alone this issue of how fast the solutions approach the zeroes of $ \ \cos x \ $ .  We can compare Taylor series expansions about those zeroes for cosine and for $ \ \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^x \  . $  The first few derivatives for $ \ 2^{-x} \ $ are

$$ [ \  2^{-x} \ ] \ ' \ = \ (- \ln 2 ) \ \cdot \  2^{-x} \ , \ [ \  2^{-x} \ ] \ '' \ = \ ( \ln 2 )^2 \ \cdot \  2^{-x} \ , \ [ \  2^{-x} \ ] \ ''' \ = \ (- \ln 2 )^3 \ \cdot \  2^{-x} \ . \  $$

$$\\$$

It will be helpful to split the solutions into two sets.  For the zeroes of cosine  $ \ \frac{(4k+1) \ \pi}{2} \ , \ k \ \ge \ 1 \ , $ the solutions to the equation lie a little "early" relative to them.  The Taylor series are

$$ \cos x \ \approx \ \cos (2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2} ) \ - \ \sin (2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2} ) \cdot \ (x - [2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}] \ ) $$

$$ - \ \frac{1}{2!} \cos (2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2} ) \cdot \ (x - [2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}] \ )^2 $$

$$ + \ \frac{1}{3!} \sin (2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2} ) \cdot \ (x - [2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}] \ )^3 \ + \ \ldots$$

$$ \approx \ - \epsilon \ + \ \frac{1}{3!} \epsilon^3 - \ \frac{1}{5!} \epsilon^5 + \ \frac{1}{7!} \epsilon^7 \ + \ \ldots \ , $$

with $ \ \epsilon \ $ being $ \ (x - [2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}] \ ) \ < \ 0 \ $ here, and

$$ 2^{-x} \ \approx \ 2^{-[2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}]} \ - \ (\ln 2) \cdot 2^{-[2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}]} \cdot (x - [2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}] \ )$$

$$  + \ \frac{1}{2!} (\ln 2)^2 \cdot 2^{-[2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}]} \cdot (x - [2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}] \ )^2 $$

$$  - \ \frac{1}{3!} (\ln 2)^3 \cdot 2^{-[2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}]} \cdot (x - [2k \pi  + \frac{\pi}{2}] \ )^3 \ + \ \ldots $$

$$ \approx \ 2^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}  \cdot \left( 2^{- 2 \pi} \right)^k \cdot [ \  1 \ - \ (\ln 2) \epsilon \ + \ \frac{1}{2!} (\ln 2)^2 \epsilon^2 \ - \ \frac{1}{3!} (\ln 2)^3 \epsilon^3 \ + \  \ldots \ ] \ . $$

It turns out that everything beyond the linear terms rapidly becomes negligible, so we can estimate the solutions increasingly well by simply setting

$$ 2^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}  \cdot \left( 2^{- 2 \pi} \right)^k \cdot [ \  1 \ - \ (\ln 2) \epsilon \ ] \ = \ - \epsilon $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \epsilon \ \approx \ -\frac{2^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}  \cdot \left( 2^{- 2 \pi} \right)^k}{1 \ - \ (\ln 2) \cdot 2^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}  \cdot \left( 2^{- 2 \pi} \right)^k} \ = \ -\frac{1}{ 2^{\frac{\pi}{2}}  \cdot \left( 2^{ 2 \pi} \right)^k \ - \ \ln 2} \ . $$

We see that the logarithm in the denominator will quickly become insignificant.  For the other zeroes of cosine at  $ \ \frac{(4k+3) \ \pi}{2} \ , \ k \ \ge \ 1 \ , $ a similar argument produces

$$ \cos x \ \approx \ \  \epsilon \ - \ \frac{1}{3!} \epsilon^3 +  \ \ldots \ \ \text{and} \ \ 2^{-x} \ \approx \ 2^{-\frac{3 \pi}{2}}  \cdot \left( 2^{- 2 \pi} \right)^k \cdot [ \  1 \ - \ (\ln 2) \epsilon \ + \ \ldots \ ] \ ,  $$

now with  $ \ \epsilon \ = \ (x - [2k \pi  + \frac{3 \pi}{2}] \ ) \ > \ 0 \ ,  $ since the solutions of the equation come "late" relative to the zeroes of cosine.  The estimate here is given by

$$ 2^{-\frac{3 \pi}{2}}  \cdot \left( 2^{- 2 \pi} \right)^k \cdot [ \  1 \ - \ (\ln 2) \epsilon \ ] \ = \  \epsilon \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \epsilon \ \approx  \  \ \frac{1}{ 2^{\frac{3 \pi}{2}}  \cdot \left( 2^{ 2 \pi} \right)^k \ + \ \ln 2} \ . $$

From this, we find that the difference of the solutions from the zeroes of cosine grow smaller with each successive period by a factor of ever closer to $ \ 2^{2 \pi} \ \approx \ 78 \ $ .  Without making this *too* tedious, we find solutions

for $ \ \frac{5 \pi}{2} \ \ (k = 1) \ : \ \ \epsilon \ \approx \ -\frac{1}{230.7} \ \Rightarrow \ x \ \approx \ 7.8496 \ ,  $

for $ \ \frac{9 \pi}{2} \ \ (k = 2) \ : \ \ \epsilon \ \approx \ -\frac{1}{18,017.5} \ \Rightarrow \ x \ \approx \ 14.137111 \ ;  $

for $ \ \frac{7 \pi}{2} \ \ (k = 1) \ : \ \ \epsilon \ \approx \ +\frac{1}{2042.4} \ \Rightarrow \ x \ \approx \ 10.99606 \ ,  $

for $ \ \frac{11 \pi}{2} \ \ (k = 2) \ : \ \ \epsilon \ \approx \ +\frac{1}{159,011} \ \Rightarrow \ x \ \approx \ 17.2787659 \ .  $

Beyond these, using the zeroes of the cosine functions *as* the equation's solutions is quite accurate.